# How to show custom error message in ValidationSummary directly (without validator)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validating

Can I set custom message to the ValidationSummary control?

I've got Delete button in the edit page. I want if the validation fail to set the error message in the validation summery to prevent putting another label with red style.

I think using CustomValidator is not a good idea in my case, because there is no validation on delete, the error message should be shown after failing the action itself.

Any help!

Answer (score 2):

you can use validation group property  to  specify which group of controls is validated on validation.you may not add delete button to that group.so clicking on delete will not fire validation.

for custom message try this [Custom Message in Validation Summary](http://www.extremeexperts.com/Net/FAQ/DisplayCustomMsgInValidationSummary.aspx)